# How to replace the value of an array item which is prop of a parent object, by using useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I am trying to make image upload `inputs` by preview, whose count is for example 5, I mean there are 5 "+" buttons which will be used to upload images.

For 5 box, I am showing below the code with Array(5). I have an object:

```
const [object, setObject] = useState[{
    name: "",
    imageUrls: Array(5)
  }]
```

When the 3rd array item of imageUrls array changes, I want to update this `object`  this way:

```
setObject({...object, imageUrls: object.imageUrls[2] = "xxx"})   // doesn't work
```

Also tried this way but again giving syntax errors.

```
setObject({...object, imageUrls[2]: "xxx"})   // doesn't work
```

What is the correct way of doing this and writing the right syntax? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:
Access the previous state snapshot, copy the object into a new reference, update the desired field, and return the new object.

```js
setObject((prevState) => {
   copy = {...prevState};
   copy.imageUrls[2] = "xxx";
   return copy;
})
```

Comment: I’m unsure if there’s a more elegant solution, but this should work.

Comment: Yes I remembered it after your suggestion, this is the most used solution